# How Can I Improve Loading Speed for My PHP-Based Website?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP-based website that displays real-time stock market data, and I'm facing issues with loading speed. The website uses PHP to scrape financial data from external sources and display it on the front end. However, the site's performance is slow. The problem is in getting the data from the website it takes around 2 minutes to load.

I'm using ajax, sessions and json.

I have tried file caching and optimizing PHP code.

Here is the PHP code that gets the data form websites:

```
<?php
session_start();
$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SMCI/");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 303;
$n = 314;
$p = 326;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberSMCI = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numSMCI = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numSMCI = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numSMCI = $numberWithPlus . "<td>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proSMCI = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proSMCI = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proSMCI = $procent . "%<br>";
}

$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 301;
$n = 312;
$p = 324;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberTSLA = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numTSLA = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numTSLA = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numTSLA = $numberWithPlus . "<br>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proTSLA = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proTSLA = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proTSLA = $procent . "%<br>";
}

$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN?p=AMZN&.tsrc=fin-srch");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 301;
$n = 312;
$p = 324;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberAMZN = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numAMZN = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numAMZN = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numAMZN = $numberWithPlus . "<br>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proAMZN = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proAMZN = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proAMZN = $procent . "%<br>";
}

//https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT&.tsrc=fin-srch

$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT&.tsrc=fin-srch");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 301;
$n = 312;
$p = 324;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberMSFT = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numMSFT = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numMSFT = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numMSFT = $numberWithPlus . "<br>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proMSFT = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proMSFT = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proMSFT = $procent . "%<br>";
}

$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD&.tsrc=fin-srch");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 301;
$n = 312;
$p = 324;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberBTC = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numBTC = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numBTC = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numBTC = $numberWithPlus . "<td>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proBTC = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proBTC = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proBTC = $procent . "%<br>";
}

//https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XRP-USD/

$vsebina = file("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XRP-USD/");
$vse = explode(" ", $vsebina[9]);

$i = 301;
$n = 312;
$p = 324;
$pattern = '/[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$i], $matches)) {
    $numberXRP = str_replace('', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$n], $matches)) {
    $numberWithPlus = $matches[0];
    if ($numberWithPlus > 0)
        $numXRP = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else if ($numberWithPlus < 0)
        $numXRP = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$numberWithPlus</span><br>";
    else
        $numXRP = $numberWithPlus . "<td>";
}
$pattern = '/[+\-]?[0-9,\.]+/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $vse[$p], $matches)) {
    $procent = str_replace(',', '', $matches[0]); // Remove commas if present
    if ($procent > 0.0)
        $proXRP = "<span style=\"color: green;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else if ($procent < 0.0)
        $proXRP = "<span style=\"color: red;\">$procent%</span><br>";
    else
        $proXRP = $procent . "%<br>";
}

$_SESSION['numberSMCI'] = $numberSMCI;
$_SESSION['gainSMCI'] = $numSMCI;
$_SESSION['procentSMCI'] = $proSMCI;

$_SESSION['numberTSLA'] = $numberTSLA;
$_SESSION['gainTSLA'] = $numTSLA;
$_SESSION['procentTSLA'] = $proTSLA;

$_SESSION['numberAMZN'] = $numberAMZN;
$_SESSION['gainAMZN'] = $numAMZN;
$_SESSION['procentAMZN'] = $proAMZN;

$_SESSION['numberMSFT'] = $numberMSFT;
$_SESSION['gainMSFT'] = $numMSFT;
$_SESSION['procentMSFT'] = $proMSFT;

$_SESSION['numberBTC'] = $numberBTC;
$_SESSION['gainBTC'] = $numBTC;
$_SESSION['procentBTC'] = $proBTC;

$_SESSION['numberXRP'] = $numberXRP;
$_SESSION['gainXRP'] = $numXRP;
$_SESSION['procentXRP'] = $proXRP;

$response = array(
    'numberSMCI' => $numberSMCI,
    'numSMCI' => $numSMCI,
    'proSMCI' => $proSMCI,
    'numberTSLA' => $numberTSLA,
    'numTSLA' => $numTSLA,
    'proTSLA' => $proTSLA,
    'numberAMZN' => $numberAMZN,
    'numAMZN' => $numAMZN,
    'proAMZN' => $proAMZN,
    'numberMSFT' => $numberMSFT,
    'numMSFT' => $numMSFT,
    'proMSFT' => $proMSFT,
    'numberBTC' => $numberBTC,
    'numBTC' => $numBTC,
    'proBTC' => $proBTC,
    'numberXRP' => $numberXRP,
    'numXRP' => $numXRP,
    'proXRP' => $proXRP
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and here is my main code that displays the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OnlineBrokers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="pictures/pillar_icon.png">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">
        <?php
            session_start();

            $numberSMCI = $_SESSION['numberSMCI'];
            $numSMCI = $_SESSION['gainSMCI'];
            $proSMCI = $_SESSION['procentSMCI'];

            $numberTSLA = $_SESSION['numberTSLA'];
            $numTSLA = $_SESSION['gainTSLA'];
            $proTSLA = $_SESSION['procentTSLA'];

            $numberAMZN = $_SESSION['numberAMZN'];
            $numAMZN = $_SESSION['gainAMZN'];
            $proAMZN = $_SESSION['procentAMZN'];

            $numberMSFT = $_SESSION['numberMSFT'];
            $numMSFT = $_SESSION['gainMSFT'];
            $proMSFT = $_SESSION['procentMSFT'];

            $numberBTC = $_SESSION['numberBTC'];
            $numBTC = $_SESSION['gainBTC'];
            $proBTC = $_SESSION['procentBTC'];

            $numberXRP = $_SESSION['numberXRP'];
            $numXRP = $_SESSION['gainXRP'];
            $proXRP = $_SESSION['procentXRP'];
        ?>
    </div>

    <script>
        function refreshContent() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "content.php?_=" + new Date().getTime(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#numberSMCI").text(data.numberSMCI);
                    $("#numSMCI").html(data.numSMCI);
                    $("#proSMCI").html(data.proSMCI);

                    $("#numberTSLA").text(data.numberTSLA);
                    $("#numTSLA").html(data.numTSLA);
                    $("#proTSLA").html(data.proTSLA);

                    $("#numberAMZN").text(data.numberAMZN);
                    $("#numAMZN").html(data.numAMZN);
                    $("#proAMZN").html(data.proAMZN);

                    $("#numberMSFT").text(data.numberMSFT);
                    $("#numMSFT").html(data.numMSFT);
                    $("#proMSFT").html(data.proMSFT);

                    $("#numberBTC").text(data.numberBTC);
                    $("#numBTC").html(data.numBTC);
                    $("#proBTC").html(data.proBTC);

                    $("#numberXRP").text(data.numberXRP);
                    $("#numXRP").html(data.numXRP);
                    $("#proXRP").html(data.proXRP);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                }
            });
        }
        refreshContent();
        setInterval(refreshContent, 2000);
    </script>

    <header>
        <div class="title">
            <h1 class="centered-content">
                <img src="pictures/pillar.png" class="titlePicture">
                <span class="pageTitle">ONLINE</span>
                <span class="pageTitle2">BROKERS</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <hr class="hrTitle">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="stocks" id="stocks">
            <table class="stockTable">
                <tr class="names">
                    <td class="stockInfo">Instrument</td>
                    <td class="stockInfo">Value</td>
                    <td class="stockInfo">Gain</td>
                    <td class="stockInfo">%</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName">SMCI<br><span class="stockNameLong">Super Micro Computer Inc.</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberSMCI"><?php echo "$numberSMCI"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numSMCI"><?php echo $numSMCI?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proSMCI"><?php echo $proSMCI?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName">TSLA<br><span class="stockNameLong">Tesla Motors</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberTSLA"><?php echo "$numberTSLA"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numTSLA"><?php echo $numTSLA?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proTSLA"><?php echo $proTSLA?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName">AMZN<br><span class="stockNameLong">Amazon.com, Inc.</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberAMZN"><?php echo "$numberAMZN"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numAMZN"><?php echo $numAMZN?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proAMZN"><?php echo $proAMZN?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName">MSFT<br><span class="stockNameLong">Microsoft Corp.</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberMSFT"><?php echo "$numberMSFT"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numMSFT"><?php echo $numMSFT?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proMSFT"><?php echo $proMSFT?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName">BTC<br><span class="stockNameLong">Bitcoin</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberBTC"><?php echo "$numberBTC"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numBTC"><?php echo $numBTC?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proBTC"><?php echo $proBTC?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="stockName">XRP<br><span class="stockNameLong">Ripple</span></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numberXRP"><?php echo "$numberXRP"?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="numXRP"><?php echo $numXRP?></td>
                    <td class="stock" id="proXRP"><?php echo $proXRP?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="stockName"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                    <td class="stock"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <h2 class="portTitle">PORTFOLIO</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hrFooter">
    <footer>
        <h5><span id="copyright">© www.copyright.com</span></h5>
    </footer>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The question isn't really appropriate for stackoverflow because no one can look at the above code and tell you why it's slow. First you need to isolate where the slowness is coming from. Is it while you are retrieving the data? If your script takes 3 seconds to load a 2.9 seconds of that is retrieving the data you know where the problem is. If retrieving the data is fast, you'd need to look at your logic, are you looping through a lot of data? Can you retrieve a smaller subset of the data at a time? etc.

Comment: Also you're using regex to parse html so this should be a good read for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: The problem is in getting the data from the website it takes around 2 minutes to load.

Comment: Okay. It seems like you have the answer then! It has nothing to do with your code. You need to find a faster source of data. I don't have any experience with these guys but maybe worth a look. https://www.alphavantage.co/ You really need json or even XML data instead of trying to scrape a site and parse.

Comment: If you can tolerate data that is a couple of minutes' old, then you could run the code that scrapes the websites in a separate process on a schedule (eg via cron) and cache the result

Comment: `session_start()` is working with all that HTML output before it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem it was `session_start()`. I had one in both PHP files and I removed one that was in the data gathering file. Now my site loads in less than a second.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).